# How to get a dense representation of one-hot vectors

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose a `Tensor` containing :

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

How to get the dense representation in a native way (without using `numpy` or iterations) ?

```
[2,1,0]
```

There is [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#one_hot) to do the inverse, there is also [`tf.sparse_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_to_dense) that seems to do it but I was not able to figure out how to use it.

Comment: The second answer (not the accepted one) is best: `tf.argmax(x, 1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vec = tf.constant([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
locations = tf.where(tf.equal(vec, 1))
# This gives array of locations of "1" indices below
# => [[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]])

# strip first column
indices = locations[:,1]
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(indices))
# => [2 1 0]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just curious about sparse_to_dense. What is it for then?

Comment: @znat TensorFlow's [`sparse_to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_to_dense) creates a dense tensor using the parameters for a SparseTensor. If you already have a SparseTensor, you could convert it to dense using [`sparse_tensor_to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_tensor_to_dense)

Comment: I just realized this is basically a verbose way of writing argmax.

Answer (score 20):

`tf.argmax(x, axis=1)` should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow does not have a native dense to sparse conversion function/helper. Given that the input array is a dense tensor, such as the one you provided, you can define a function to convert a dense tensor to a sparse tensor.

```py
def dense_to_sparse(dense_tensor):
    where_dense_non_zero = tf.where(tf.not_equal(dense_tensor, 0))
    indices = where_dense_non_zero
    values = tf.gather_nd(dense_tensor, where_dense_non_zero)
    shape = dense_tensor.get_shape()

    return tf.SparseTensor(
        indices=indices,
        values=values,
        shape=shape
    )
```

This helper function finds the indices and values where the Tensor is non-zero and outputs a Sparse tensor with those indices and values. Additionally, the shape is effectively copied over.

You do not want to use `tf.sparse_to_dense` as that gives you the opposite representation. If you want your output to be `[2, 1, 0]` instead, you'll need to index the indices. First, you'll need the indices where the array isn't 0:

`indices = tf.where(tf.not_equal(dense_tensor, 0))`

Then, you'll need to access the tensor using slicing/indicing:

`output = indices[:, 1]`

You might notice that 1 in the slice above is equivalent to the dimension of the tensor - 1. Therefore, to make these value generic, you could do something like:

`output = indices[:, len(dense_tensor.get_shape()) - 1]`

Although I'm not exactly sure what you'd do with these values (the value of the column where the value is). Hope this helped!

**EDIT**: Yaroslav's answer is better if you're looking for the indices/locations of where the input tensor if 1; it won't be extensible for tensors with non-1/0 values if that is required.