# Argmax on tf.sparse.SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, sparse-matrix

Given a Sparse Tensor x of shape [B, d, d', v], how can I calculate `tf.argmax(x, axis=2)` while keeping sparsity?

```
x = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(values=..., indices=..., shape=[B, d1, d2, v])
# How to implement something like
sparse_argmax(x, axis=2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964424/how-to-get-a-dense-representation-of-one-hot-vectors/45623979) has some options that seem to match your use case - you'll probably need to convert to a dense tensor before applying argmax.

Comment: The whole point is to not use dense tensors.

Comment: Right - to the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible with the built-in functions.

Comment: You can create a custom sparse_argmax() function using tf.sparse.reduce_max() and tf.boolean_mask()

Comment: Could you please go into detail a bit on how this would be done (in a performant way)?

Comment: Converted the sparse tensor to dense tensor ,used tf.math.argmax() to get its index (have to proceed further to keep the sparsity) , providing GIST for reference.                   https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/15902b18281e4f0dcacfba24d1c00391/stack_67811443.ipynb